# Unlock Windows From OSX Terminal

Tags: windows, macos, terminal, remote-access, wake-on-lan

What I am trying to achieve is to have a fully automated boot and login script to remotely start up and log in to my windows gaming host for steam in home streaming. So far I have installed wakeonlan through homebrew and that part is working fine, yet I c an't seem to find any way to log in to the remote computer from the terminal.
I have seen some Windows apps people have made for this exactly, yet they all run in powershell and C, and I have no clue how I could make that work on OSX.

Comment: MS Remote Desktop for Mac? https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12 or you need to do this from terminal and no 3rd party software?

Comment: While it works, the objective is to be fully automated, from the terminal. 3rd party software is fine, as long as it can be run from the terminal with no user input.

Comment: Please check this question and its answer : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54918/command-line-arguments-for-remote-desktop-connection-for-mac

Comment: How would you use that to connect to the remote host and then run a command (tscon) to end the connection without locking the remote host, without leaving anything open in the end?